# show pseudo element but not parent element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

Hi I have a list item containing text like this:

```
<li>Search</li>
```

and I want to display an icon using font awesome

```
li:before {
  content: "\f002";
}
```

I don't have the ability to just remove the "Search" text (it is being generated from a Drupal CMS, as is the markup and class names), but I want to hide the Search text, but show the pseudo element (the search icon). How do I do this? Normally what I would do to hide the text is just go:

```
li {
  text-indent: -1000px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

but that will hide the pseudo element as well

Comment: are you able to add a span inside li ? if you are then just do "li span { display:none}"

Comment: This is pretty hacky, and don't tell anyone I did this, but, http://jsfiddle.net/57BGV/

Comment: I think you better handle in that CMS itself.

Comment: @Evan you're right - it's ugly...but that's what I asked for. Thanks for the tip. If you write it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can stick to the "text-indent" method (or better the "[Kellum Method](http://www.zeldman.com/2012/03/01/replacing-the-9999px-hack-new-image-replacement/)") and use CSS positioning for the pseudo element:

```
li {
display:block;
position:relative;
text-indent: -100%;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
}
li:after {
content: "visible pseudo-element";
position:absolute;
right:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fiddel/aopteq8m/

Comment: I could still see a little of the original element, but changing to `text-indent: -110%` and `right:-5%` did the trick

Answer (score 6):

A bit late to the party, but you could always change the font-size of the li to 0, and change the font-size of the icon back to the original font-size. Like this:

```
li {
    font-size: 0;
}

li:after {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Nice and easy! Great!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty hacky, and don't tell anyone I did this, but [jsfiddle.net/57BGV](http://jsfiddle.net/57BGV).

```
li {
    list-style: none;
    text-indent: -65px;
}

li:after {
    content: "Test";
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to change the font-color to whatever the background-color is. This won't remove the text from the flow but will hide it, which is what you're asking, technically.

Assuming your background is white:

```
li {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Comment: It has a background image, otherwise this seems like a somewhat viable solution.

Comment: If it has a background of any sort, `color: transparent` is a better option.