# Parent replacement with text-indent

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply the *text-indent technique* ([show pseudo element but not parent element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060352/show-pseudo-element-but-not-parent-element)) to hide the text into the parent container and just show the added *content* into a pseudo-element.

The markup I have is something like:

```
<a href="" class="icon">@</a>
```

but it could also have not exclusively text inside:

```
<a href="" class="icon"><img src="pic.jpg" /></a>

<a href="" class="icon"><div>Some text in a block with its own <element>, <img src="img.jpg" /> or CSS styling</div></a>
```

And then the CSS:

```
.icon {
    position: relative !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    text-indent: -100% !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
}

.icon:before {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    content: "\xe000";
}
```

(the **!important** clause is there cause the icon should have priority on whatever is inside the element content.)

The problem are that:

- the container moves, but is **still visible**, while I want to hide it completely.
- changing *text-indent* changes for **both the container AND the pseudo-element**.

I am testing on **Firefox 39.0**.

What do I miss?

PS - I obviously don't want to just change the color of the text into the container to hide it.

Answer (score 2):

Text-indent work with display `block` or `inline-block`

```css
    .icon {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-indent: -100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .icon:before {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        content: "\xe000";
        text-indent: 0;
    }
```

```html
<a  class="icon">@</a>
```

Or in this case, you can use font-size instead text-indent

```css
.icon {
  font-size: 0;
}

.icon:before {
  content: "test";
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="icon">@</a>
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, that's feasible, but I still wonder why the **text-indent** doesn't work the way it is supposed to work (I guess the **text-indent hack** would not exist if it were normal for *text-indent* to affect **both** the container and the pseudo-element, isn't it?). ... the fact is that the element where I add the class could contain anything, not just text (I'll update the question).

Comment: I've just updated my answer, the **text-indent** not work with display "inline"

Comment: Thanks, I found myself to reset many properties with **!important** (to avoid conflicts with the original styling of the elements) but that works now! Nice answer :) ____ A last detail: **is it possible to position the pseudo-element in a better way?** (like aligning it *horizontally/vertically* relative to the container dimensions) Cause **actually it lays on the left side** while I'd need the pseudo-element to lay in the middle of the space occupied by the container.

Comment: If you want to align many positions, I think your current way is Ok. You can read more about align center in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)